# PHP select inner index in first iteration of foreach loop in a nested array of objects

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array, nested-loops

I know this may sound weird or repetitive, but I have an special requirement, where I got a nested array of objects, which I am trying to display in a Slick slider. The goal is to display outer array (which also serves as an index of inner array) as Slick slides of dates, and inner arrays of objects as the content of that slide available on that date. here is var_dump of my array:

```
    array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#36 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "9"
        ["title"]=>
        string(16) "Chemistray Class"
        ["found_dates"]=>
        string(19) "2016-08-01 00:00:00"

      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#40 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "6"
        ["title"]=>
        string(10) "Math Class"
        ["found_dates"]=>
        string(19) "2016-08-01 00:00:00"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#37 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "9"
        ["title"]=>
        string(16) "Chemistray Class"
        ["found_dates"]=>
        string(19) "2016-08-02 00:00:00"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#41 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "6"
        ["title"]=>
        string(10) "Math Class"
        ["found_dates"]=>
        string(19) "2016-08-02 00:00:00"
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#38 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "9"
        ["title"]=>
        string(16) "Chemistry Class"
        ["found_dates"]=>
        string(19) "2016-08-03 00:00:00"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#42 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "6"
        ["title"]=>
        string(10) "Math Class"
        ["found_dates"]=>
        string(19) "2016-08-03 00:00:00"
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#43 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "6"
        ["title"]=>
        string(10) "Math Class"
        ["found_dates"]=>
        string(19) "2016-08-04 00:00:00"
      }
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#39 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "9"
        ["title"]=>
        string(16) "Chemistry Class"
        ["found_dates"]=>
        string(19) "2016-09-04 00:00:00"
      }
    }
  }
```

here is my php code:

```
 <?php 
  ksort($searches);

  $searches = array_values($searches);

    if(count($searches) > 0){ $count = 0; ?>

      <div class="dates-slick-slider">

       <?php foreach($searches as $key => $sr){

         $date = new DateTime($sr[$key]->found_dates); ?>

         <p><?= $date->format('M d Y'); ?></p>

           <?php foreach ($sr as $key => $search) { ?>

                  <div>$search->title</div>

      <?php }  }  } ?>

      </div>
```

My problem is: I can successfully extract and display any data in inner loop, but as you can see, the outer loop doesn't hold the correct offset always, as some of the sub arrays hold more than one objects, thus it fails. It can display only those values (dates), which have single objects in array, but if number of objects exceeds 1, it shows undefined offset error, which off course is correct, as it doesn't know which object's '$found_dates' variable it has to extract. I have tried numerous ways, but can't think any way I can do that.

Is there anybody who can shade some light on this or suggest some way to do this?

All comments and answers are welcome and already thanked!

Comment: Please provide array $searches without print_r it.

Comment: You are overwriting `$key` in your inner loop. Call it something else e.g. `$key_inner`

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Thank you. I have updated my question with the var_dump of array, without print_r().

Comment: @rjdown I changed the inner key to $key_inner, its no more overwritting, yet the problem persists: 'undefined offset:2' and also 'Trying to get property of non-object' on those arrays, where objects are more than one. Help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Zafar It's not look like an array in PHP?

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn its an array being sent by a query from database, which I have already sorted back in my modal. in what connection doesn't it look like an php array?
Also, I have used CI's Active Records to fetch it from DB and then re-arranged the array as per indices and finally I have run array_merge($seraches) method on it, back in modal.